# Amazon EC2 connection time out Error

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying amazon web service to deploy my application built in CakePHP 3.0 . I have created ec2 instance with ubuntu 12.04. i followed every amazon documentation steps but i am getting Following Error:

1) Time Error while connecting with amazon instance
[Time out Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykntl.jpg)

2) System log Error
[Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x69SG.jpg)

Following settings i have done with my ec2 instance :

1) Security Group : I have allowed HTTP, HTTPS, ICMP access
2) Network Access : i have also allowed network access
to my IP
3) Converted .pem private key to .ppk using putty

But after follow all steps i am getting Time Out Error. What should i do

Please Help,

Thank you

Comment: Is SSH (port 22) open in the security group for your IP address as well?

Comment: yes i have opened for ssh,http and https all ports which is necessary

Comment: Do you know whether the instance has a public IP adress or only an internal AWS IP address?

Comment: yes i know where is public IP address and Public DNS i have used both to connect with amazon instance using putty. But it shows me Connection Time Out Error

Answer (score 0):

Got to `Description tab` and click on `Security Group` click on `Inbound` then `edit --> Add Rule Type --> ssh, Source --> Anywhere` . It should work for you.